# Looking up and inserting values from a table

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset of reaction times from a psycholinguistic experiment, and in separate tables, I have information that I'd like to add in about each word's frequency and things like that.

The main dataset looks something like this:

```
maindataset <-structure(list(item = c(101, 103, 102, 104, 104, 102, 103,
102, 101, 103, 104, 101), react = c(512, 510, 506, 499, 515, 516,
517, 518, 509, 599, 520, 523), prime = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("item", "react", "prime"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the frequency information looks like this:

```
frequencyinfo <-structure(list(item = c(101, 102, 103, 104), 
frequency = c(10,30, 40, 50)), .Names = c("item", "frequency"), 
row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

So basically, for each value of item in maindataset, I want to look up the frequency from the frequency table, and store it in a new column in maindataset.
I've been able to do it in the past using for loops, but it's horribly inefficient (it takes minutes to go through the whole 10,000 row dataset). Anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6):

If I interpreted your question properly, then you want to use `merge()`:

```
merge(maindataset, frequencyinfo)
   item react prime frequency
1   101   512     1        10
2   101   523     3        10
3   101   509     2        10
4   102   506     3        30
....
....
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right) on stack overflow provides a very nice overview of the different options for merge. If you are familiar with SQL, you can draw some very nice parallels to the different [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) operators.